# Unknown custom element: <firstcomponent> - did you register the component correctly

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

I am a beginner at Vue.js and i am having trouble creating my first component , I gave my component a name and i think i register it correctly but i am having the  **Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.** error .
What am i missing

Here is my `FirstComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Title</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Send it from Vue Js
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "firstcomponent",
    mounted() {
     console.log("Component mounted successfully");
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import FirstComponent from "./components/FirstComponent";

// window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('firstcomponent', require('./components/FirstComponent.vue'));

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'firstcomponent': FirstComponent
    }
})
```

And my blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <template>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="content">
                <firstcomponent></firstcomponent>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
@endsection
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `Vue.component('firstcomponent', require('./components/FirstComponent.vue'));` ?

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js, you should define which should be exported from the component. Use default will work fine:

```
Vue.component('firstcomponent', require('./components/FirstComponent.vue').default);
```

Comment: That did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry. It's true that either adding `.default` or not works fine in my local environment. 
You may check you complile setting.